# Unity- How to get a time instant?

Tags: ios, time, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to create a swipe function to work in iOS devices. I've calculated the start touch position and the end touch position. Now, I want to calculate the start time and end time to get a time difference between the two touch events.

I've tried `Time.time` and `Time.deltatime` but as You already know It didn't work. So Please Help. Or if have any better suggestions for swipe, then please suggest me.

Thank You.

Comment: I don't have time to pull up the docs on Unity Input, but try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com. You'll get a more active response since that stackexchange is 50% unity questions.

Comment: what's wrong with using Time.time when you first detect the touch? It's been a while since I've worked on a Unity IOS project, but I remember doing something similar by created a start time using Time.time when the touch phase was "Began" and concluding it when the touch phase was "Ended". Whats the actual problem you're having with using Time.time. some example code could help

Comment: @brandon its giving me a constant start time, since it calculates the time since the game start and end time has the same problem and it goes on increasing

Comment: What is the problem in that? What information are you looking for? How do the standard functions not provide that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what brandon is implying is you need to record Time.time in a variable such as startTime where you detect start touch then where you are recording the end touch do something like:

```
diffTime = Time.time - startTime
```

EDIT: Based on your comment I'm assuming it didn't work.  Without your code its hard to say where you're getting lost but I'll try a psuedo code example in C# (don't know whether you're using Boo, C#, or Javascript):

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour {

    public float startTime;
    public float diffTime;


    void Update() {

        if (/* DETECT TOUCH START */ ) {
            startTime = Time.time;  // Record startTime in secs since game start.

        }

        if (/* DETECT TOUCH END */ ) {
            diffTime = Time.time - startTime;  // Record diffTime in secs since startTime.
            Debug.Log("startTime / diffTime = " +  startTime + " / " +  diffTime);
            startTime = 0;  // Reset startTime.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is startTime = Time.time or Time.deltatime?

Comment: I've already tried it. Just asking for confirmation that's it.